# Wordpress - next_post_link() not filtering by post_type showing nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add previous and next links to my portfolio posts. I have various custom posts, but I only want to link to my portfolio custom posts.

I have been looking in the documentation and have tried using this in the wordpress loop

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', true);  ?>
```

This returns nothing.

If I use

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post in category', false);  ?>
```

It returns a link, but it links to a different custom post from a different post type.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by doing the following,

1. Performing a WordPress query getting all of the relevant posts
   for the post type 'portfolio'
2. Declare an array of IDS and put each post ID inside.
3. Get the index from the array of the current post
4. Check the page exists, if show display the link to the page

   ```
               // get_posts in same custom taxonomy
               $postlist_args = array(
                  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
                  'order'           => 'ASC',
                  'post_type'       => 'portfolio',
               ); 

               $postlist = get_posts( $postlist_args );

               // get ids of posts retrieved from get_posts
               $ids = array();
               foreach ($postlist as $thepost) {
                  $ids[] = $thepost->ID;
               }

               //Get index of current post        
               $thisindex = array_search($this_post_id, $ids);

               //Check to see if pages exist
               if(isset($ids[$thisindex-1]))
               {
                   $previd = $ids[$thisindex-1];
                   echo '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($previd). '">previous</a>';

               }
               if(isset($ids[$thisindex+1]))
               {
                   $nextid = $ids[$thisindex+1];
                   if ( !empty($nextid) ) {
                       echo '<a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($nextid). '">next</a>';
                   }
               }

               /**  End of function  **/
           ?>
   ```

This is adjusted for my solution, credit

http://bucketpress.com/next-and-previous-post-link-in-same-custom-taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter accepted by `next_post_link()` indicates whether the next post must be within the same taxonomy term as the current post. If set to `true`, only posts from the current taxonomy term will be displayed. As you can see, it has no bearing on the **type** of post.

Therefore, you will need to use an alternative function.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Comment: So there is no way to categorise a custom post type so that it will show them for the next link?

Comment: Not using the `next_post_link()` function.